# How to install flask-mysqldb on Mac OSX?

Tags: python, macos, mysql-python

I tried

```
sudo pip3 install flask-mysqldb
```

but got the following error:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-3l4jec4_/mysqlclient/

Comment: Try using `pip` instead pf `pip3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just install it via *pip install flask-mysqldb*, it's python3 compatible.

Answer (score 5):

The solution above works

```
conda install -c bioconda mysqlclient
```

Then run

```
pip install flask-mysqldb
```

Anaconda is a must have for python anyway.

Answer (score 4):

First set your mysql path by giving the command

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

Then, use below to install flask-mysqldb,

```
pip3 install flask-mysqldb
```

then use library 'flask_mysqldb' in python.

Comment: this works after installing `brew install mysql-client`

Answer (score 2):

If you have anaconda installed, you can try the following:

1. `conda install -c bioconda mysqlclient`
2. `pip install flask-mysqldb`

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

After successfully install the flask-mysqldb, use it as:

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
```

Answer (score 0):

For macOS without Conda, using Homebrew and pip, you can install Flask-MySQLdb.

First, install the MySQL client library: `brew install mysql`

Then, try installing Flask-MySQLdb again: `pip install Flask-MySQLdb`